# "Mega" Dynamic acces to static method/property in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, syntax, static

Having this 2 classes:

```
class run {
   public static $where = "there";
}

class there {
   public static $place_name = "A beautiful place..";
}
```

To get place_name I can do this:

```
$place = "there";
echo $place::$place_name;
```

But I might want to do something like this at some point..:

```
echo {$run::$where}::$place_name;
```

Obviously, the last snippet doesn't work.
Is there any way to make it do work?

Comment: erm.. maybe simply with eval..? of course it is a bad practice it you overdo it.. but in reasonable cases, it's very handy.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php BUT: it is **slow**. If you find any other way -- use that other way!

Comment: Why not `$place = $run::$where; echo $place::$place_name;`?

Comment: Shure, I cand do that, but this way I would skip this too..

Comment: Does it work without the curlies?

Comment: Duh, this one is obvious, isn't it? `${!${''}=$run::$where}::$place_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use a variable (as you said in a comment), think twice. Variables are cool in PHP, very fast and just the needed glue to work-around its limited parser (which of it was said makes PHP quite fast). So why not use a variable here? It's easy to type and quickly done.

If you don't want the variable and as we already have found out that PHP's syntax is limited, you can at least write a one-liner with PHP 5.4+ to achieve what you're looking for:

```
echo (new ReflectionClass((new ReflectionClass($run))->getStaticPropertyValue('where')))->getStaticPropertyValue('place_name');
```

which then finally should make visible that using a variable is more comfortable:

```
echo (unset) $place = $run::$where, $place::$place_name;
```

Demo: http://eval.in/13942